# How to move files from one folder to another efficiently in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, directory, operating-system

I have a folder which contains a bunch of sub-folders that have not been organized properly something like this [image]

Now, I want to create a new directory and group the common files together something like. How to efficiently handle this in python?     [image]

Comment: Your original folder structure contains 3 files named common1 but your output only has one file with that name. How do you decide which file (named common1) to place in the output structure? Also, it looks like you forgot to post the Python code you're currently struggling with

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, all the 3 are same files --  doesn't matter which file to keep. I'll post the code which I'm struggling with